# kendo grid in edit mode: correlation between field controls

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid where in edit mode I need to disable and clear the combo box of one field when a specific item is selected in another.  I know i can do this with Jquery outside the context of the kendo control, but im thinking there has got to be a better way to do this within the kendo context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit) event of the grid and find any widget of interest. Use the container field of the event argument.